# Web API can't deserialize a Javascript Date.toISOString()?

Tags: c#, javascript, json, datetime, deserialization

I'm looking for a way to pass javascript dates to .NET web api controllers without installing another library on the client...

I'm expecting the javascript dates to deserialize to .NET DateTime.

```
var date = new Date(); 
post({currentDate: date.toISOString()});
```

Arrives at server as a DateTime.Min (indicating it failed to deserialize).

Here's an example of what is being sent over the wire, but the ApiController is not able to create a DateTime with the correct date...

Request:

```
{"Date":"2014-04-16T17:03:03.383Z"}
```

C#:

```
    [Serializable]
    public class MyObj 
    {
         public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyController : ApiController
    {
        public HttpResponseMessage Post(MyObj dd)
        {
            // dd's Date property equals DateTime.Min rather than the correct date...
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's being passed correctly? Javascript's Date.toISOString() should return a string in the format of "2014-04-10T03:56:12.238Z", which is a format that C# DateTime.Parse should be able to handle.

Comment: are you looking for ISO timestamps?

Comment: I am sure that the timestamps are coming through as: 2014-04-16T17:03:03.383Z but not getting parsed correctly into a DateTime using an ApiController with a method that accepts an object with DateTime inside of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the [Serializable] attribute.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should push the ticks from the client side. Then the server side will get a date from the ticks.
Example:

Javascipt:

```
var date = new Date(); 
post({ticks: date.getTime()});
```

.NET:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(ticks);
```

Comment: I would have to create a DTO and use ints for all my dates in my object graph, and write special code to unpack all the ticks into DateTimes.  Is Web API really this lousy?